# Spring Transactional method not working properly (not saving db)

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, transactional

I have spent day after day trying to find a solution for my problem with Transactional methods. The logic is like this:
Controller receive request, call queueService, put it in a PriorityBlockingQueue and another thread process the data (find cards, update status,assign to current game, return data)

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/queue")
public DeferredResult<List<Card>> queueRequest(@Params...){
queueService.put(result, size, terminal, time) 
result.onCompletion(() ->  assignmentService.assignCards(result, game,room, cliente));
}
```

QueueService:

```
@Service
public class QueueService {
 private BlockingQueue<RequestQueue> queue = new PriorityBlockingQueue<>();

 @Autowired
 GameRepository gameRepository;
 @Autowired
 TerminalRepository terminalRepository;
 @Autowired
 RoomRpository roomRepository;

 private long requestId = 0;

 public void put(DeferredResult<List<Card>> result, int size, String client, LocalDateTime time_order){

        requestId++;

        --ommited code(find Entity: game, terminal, room)

        try {
            RequestQueue request= new RequestCola(requestId, size, terminal,time_order, result);
            queue.put(request);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }
```

CardService:

```
@Transactional
public class CardService {

@Autowired
EntityManager em;
@Autowired
CardRepository cardRepository;
@Autowired
AsignService asignacionService;

public List<Cards> processRequest(int size, BigDecimal value)
{

    List<Card> carton_query = em.createNativeQuery("{call cards_available(?,?,?)}",
            Card.class)           
            .setParameter(1, false)
            .setParameter(2, value)
            .setParameter(3, size).getResultList();

    List<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();
    carton_query.forEach(action -> ids.add(action.getId_card()));
    String update_query = "UPDATE card SET available=true WHERE id_card IN :ids";
    em.createNativeQuery(update_query).setParameter("ids", ids).executeUpdate();

    return card_query;
}
```

QueueExecutor (Consumer)

```
@Component
public class QueueExecute {

@Autowired
QueueService queueRequest;
@Autowired
AsignService asignService;
@Autowired
CardService cardService;

@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    new Thread(this::execute).start();
}

private void execute(){

    while (true){
        try {

            RequestQueue request;
            request = queueRequest.take();

            if(request != null) {
                List<Card> cards = cardService.processRequest(request.getSize(), new BigDecimal("1.0"));
                request.getCards().setResult((ArrayList<Card>) cards);  
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

}

AssignService:

```
@Transactional 
public void assignCards(DeferredResult<List<Card>> cards, Game game, Room room, Terminal terminal)
{

        game = em.merge(game);
        room = em.merge(room);
        terminal = em.merge(terminal);

        Order order = new Order();
        LocalDateTime datetime = LocalDateTime.now();
        BigDecimal total = new BigDecimal("0.0");
        order.setTime(datetime)
        order.setRoom(room);
        order.setGame(game);
        order.setId_terminal(terminal);

        for(Card card: (List<Card>)cards.getResult()) {
            card= em.merge(card)
        --> System.out.println("CARD STATUS" + card.getStatus());
// This shows the OLD value of the Card (not updated)
            card.setOrder(order); 
            order.getOrder().add(card); 

        }

        game.setOrder(order);
//gameRepository.save(game)
```

}

With this code, it does not save new Card status on DB but Game, Terminal and Room saves ok on DB (more or less...). If I remove the assignService, CardService saves the new status on DB correctly.

I have tried to flush manually, save with repo and so on... but the result is almost the same. Could anybody help me?

Comment: I just scanned through the code and it looks like you are starting a new thread to do the transaction. The context of the transaction is lost when you spawn the new thread and this causes the transaction to not be committed. Can you try running everything in the same thread and check if it works? Because maybe your question is how to do things asynchronously rather if transactions work or not.

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by running everything in the same thread... Move the logic of assignCards method to the cardService method? Do all the stuff in a single transaction? If you're saying this, I have tested it also but shows another error: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : package.Card.order-> package.Order]

Comment: replace this  `new Thread(this::execute).start();`  with `execute();`

Comment: If i replace that as you say the program does not start up, it hangs on there:
services.QueueExecute     init

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution (probably not the optimum), but it's more related to the logic of my program.

One of the main problems was the update of Card status property, because it was not reflected on the entity object. When the assignOrder method is called it received the *old* Card value because it's not possible to share information within Threads/Transactions (as far I know). This is normal within transactions because em.executeUpdate() only commits database, so if I want to get the updated entity I need to refresh it with em.refresh(Entity), but this caused performance to go down.

At the end I changed the logic: first create Orders (transactional) and then assign cards to the orders (transactional). This way works correctly.